# CSS: Top of page after page jump

Tags: css, css-position, page-jump

I have an html page that i must not modify, and everything i do it must be done with CSS.

I hava 4 "section" tags in the html page, and on the top of that page there is a navigation bar. Each element of the bar is an internal link (page jump) to a specific section of the same page.

Normally, when i click on one of these links, the first row of the suitable section will appear on top of my page.

But i have modified the position of the navigation bar, so it will always stay on top (position:fixed).

So when i click on 1 section button, the first row (and 1 or 2 more rows) of the chosen section, are covered by my navigation bar ... :(

What i want is a solution, so when i click one option on my navigation bar, then the first rows of the selected section will not appear on the top of the screen, but just under my bar.

If some code is necessary, please ask specific parts, because it is long enough.

Comment: It would be best if you could build a simple demo that exhibits the issue you are describing. If you can't do that, then a simple page showing the overall structure (i.e. the navbar and the four sections, and any surrounding elements etc.) along with the CSS that is relevant to the included structure.

Comment: well, here are 2 screenshots.

1) this is how it should be, when i press the suitable button on the bar. you can see that the "RED LETTER" row is the top of the section
http://ompldr.org/vOHI1eA/1.png

2) this is how it IS. you can see that the "RED LETTER" row hides behind my logo and my bar
http://ompldr.org/vOHI2Mg/2.png

In html, i have "section" tags, each of them has its own "id" value.
Every button of my bar, uses an "a" tag, where the "href" field has for value, the suitable "id" of the section.

Comment: You want code, so present code - are people supposed to guess both your markup and styling?

Comment: this is the part for "header" tag, which contains the bar and the logo.................body > header {
 position:fixed;
 z-index:2;
 background-color:white;
 top:0px;
}..........

Comment: in html i have  "<header>...</header> <section>...</section>".......

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried applying a positive `padding-top` to the sections, and then canceling out that padding with a negative `margin-top`? The value of both would be the desired gap between the section and the top edge of the screen after clicking the jump length.

Comment: it works !!!!! dude, you are either a css guru, or simply a genius !! thanks a lot! you saved my day ;)  .